# Why is the asp.net checkbox not disabled?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to set the disabled property for my `CheckBox` to true. However, when I do a postback the `CheckBox` is still enabled?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("#CheckBoxList1_0").attr('disabled',true);
            }
    );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>een</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>twee</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>drie</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**c#:**

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!CheckBoxList1.Items[0].Enabled)
            {
                Response.Write("it is disabled");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use a `CheckBoxList` instead of three separate `CheckBox`es? If you use a real `CheckBox`, you can use the property `Enabled` and set it to `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS properties like `disabled` added with jQuery, or added in any way for that matter, will not post to the server when you do a postback.

If you really need to keep track of which checkboxes are disabled, one way to accomplish this would be to store those elements' ids into a hidden input, the value of which *will* post to the server.

Something like this should work

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="yourHiddenInput" />

$("form").submit(function(){
    var allIds = [];
    $("input[type='checkbox']:disabled").each(function() {
       allIds.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    $("#yourHiddenInput").val(allIds.join());

    //form is about to post.  When it does, 
    //you'll be able to read the ids via yourHiddenInput.Value
});
```

Comment: If you have a check box and you disable it with jQuery (set disabled = disabled), then it does have an effects on the server, albeit not what you'd likely expect. With disabled set, the server-side ignores the "checked" value of that control. If you don't disable it, the server sees the correct value of the check box. It doesn't affect the server's concept of item.Enabled, or even item.Attributes["disabled"].

Answer (score 1):

When you change the checkbox using javascript that change is on the client only, I believe that the viewstate information for the checkbox won't be updated and so when the postback occurs as far as the page knows the checkbox is still unchecked

Comment: The example isn't about "checking" the check box.

Even so, you are wrong: changing the "checked" state of a checkbox with js propagates to the server as you'd expect.